# Having trouble understanding return type placement( Big Java Ex 6.8)

Tags: java

Currently on the chapter in my book where we talk about for loops and loops. I have sometimes come across an issue where the method needs me to return something. For example consider my code
below. Basically the exercise is to get all the factors in ascending order. Now heres the issue

As you can see I need a return statement outside of the for loop. Now I guess my book didn't exactly explain this properly, or I didn't understand the concept
of return properly in java, but does our return statement always have to be in the most outer indentation if you will?

The thing is, I don't really want to return anything outside of the for loop. I just want to return `i` upon that condition. Why doesn't java let me do this? 
Whats a good counter-action?

Ever since I started learning loops and for loops, I have been having trouble understanding this. I guess I could just `system.out.println(i)` instead of returning it? But then what should I `return`? I could also make it a `void` type, and then make another method to print it, I guess?

```
class factors{

    private int num;

    public factors(int num)
    {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getFactors()
    {
        for(int i = 1 ; i<num ; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
         // I NEED TO PUT A RETURN STATEMENT HERE

    }   
}

public class test{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        factors fact = new factors(20);
        System.out.println(fact.getFactors());
    }
}
```

IT WORKS NOW ( I dont particularly like my solution)

```
class factors{

    private int num;

    public factors(int num)
    {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void getFactors()
    {
        for(int i = 1 ; i<num ; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }

        }   
    }





}

public class test{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        factors fact = new factors(20);
        fact.getFactors();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that a function that returns something has to return exactly once, and that a function *stops going* when it returns? That loop isn't going to return all factors, and if it doesn't find any factors at all (maybe `num == 1`), it's not going to hit a `return` statement at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The thing is, I don't really want to return anything outside of the for loop. I just want to return i upon that condition. Why doesn't java let me do this?

Java lets you do that. There is nothing wrong with returning inside the loop upon reaching the condition.

Java allows you to have multiple return statements, so adding another `return 0;` after the loop is allowed.

Java returns once it hits the *first* return statement, and other return statements are *not* executed (the method isn't executed anymore) (except for some rare edge cases with try-catch and return, but thats another story entirely).

**But why is it required?**

Java requires that for *all possible paths* there exists a `return` with the proper type. Even if you yourself can proof mathematically that the path Java complains about is never taken, the compiler might not be able to prove that the path is not possible *at runtime*. So you simply need to add an return there with a dummy value.

*In your concrete example*, there is a condition in which the loop gets never executed. If `num <= 0`, then the loop condition is never satified and the entire loop body is skipped. Without the return,the method is invalid, because you can't return nothing from an method with return type `int`.

So, in your example, the compiler is actually smarter then you, and prevents you from making a mistake - because it found the path you thought wouldn't occur.

```
new factors(-1).getFactors(); // you don't check the passed value at all ;)
```

---

From your comments, it seems that you want to return all factors. In java, you return once, and only once, from a function. This means you have to aggregate the results and return a `List` or `array` of values:

```
public List<Integer> getFactors(int num) {
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1 ; i<num ; i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            factors.add(i);
        }
    }
    return factors;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new factors(20).getFactors());
    // prints a comma-separated list of all factors
}
```

Comment: This is a great explanation +1. I added my working code, for some reason it looks very poorly structured, can you add your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> does our return statement always have to be in the most outer indentation if you will?

No.

***However***, *all* potential code paths *must* return something.  Consider this structure:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i<num ; i++)
{
    if (num % i == 0)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

What happens if `num` is a value where the loop itself is never entered?  Or what happens if the `if` condition is never satisfied?  No `return` statement would ever be encountered, which is invalid.

The compiler has to guarantee that the method will return *something*, under any and all potential runtime conditions.  So while it's perfectly valid to return from within the loop, you also must provide logic for what to return if that `return` statement is never reached.

Comment: But I don't want to return anything in my else statement, whats the counter action then? If it was a string usually I would just do return "", just for the sake of the program to run? I was thinking about making this void. But then Im not sure how I would get all the values of i in another printer method.

Comment: @cresjoy: The method returns an `int`, so all code paths *must* return an `int` somewhere.  If the method is `void` then no code paths can return a value.  Logically it's really up to you to define what the method *does* and what its returned value *means*.  But if you declare the method to return an `int` then, well, you have to return an `int`.  It's not even really clear to me what this method is *supposed* to be doing.

Comment: Right. So what I meant was I would make a void method which will actually have all the values of i, and then another method which would actually return those values. However I'm wondering if thats possible as I havent studied arrays in java yet.

Comment: I'm just confused as to what my else statement to return. As I dont want it to return anything

Comment: @cresjoy: What you're describing doesn't make any sense to me.  One method to "have values" and another method to "return those values"?  What does that even mean?

Comment: Basically, a getter and a setter.

Comment: @cresjoy: Ok, then I guess make a getter and a setter.  That's not even close to what you have here, so it's still not clear to me what you're even trying to build with this code.

Comment: If I put an else statement in the for loop, ( I did else { return 1}) why does it still tell me I need to return something? That seems odd

Comment: @cresjoy: Because there's still no `return` statement if the loop is never entered in the first place.  ***All*** potential logical code paths in the method must return a value.  Not just some or most.  All.

Comment: I just realized in my book they told me to make two methods. So mabye returning all the factors in one method in the first place isn't possible? I'll try making a getter and setter method and let you know.

Comment: @cresjoy: `"mabye returning all the factors in one method in the first place isn't possible"` - It is.  But not with the code you've written.

Comment: Can I have a hint? I'm stuck

Comment: @cresjoy: So, what exactly do you want this method to provide as a return value?  Currently it provides a single `int` value.  "All the factors" implies a collection of values.  You can't represent many integers with a single `int`.  The method would have to return a collection of some kind (array, list, etc.).

Comment: "However, _all_ potential code paths _must_ return something" -- unless they `throw` something.

Comment: I want to return a variable such that the modulus is 0 on every iteration. Should I just system.out.println, that variable on every iteration? I feel like Im confusing myself. I havent learned arrays yet btw

Comment: @bradimus: Fair enough.  All logical paths must provide a reasonable exit from the method.

Comment: @cresjoy: You do seem to be confusing yourself.  You can't "return on every iteration".  Once you return a value, the method is done executing.  The scope of execution "returns" to the calling method.

Comment: We havent learned arrays yet, so is the only option just to system.out.println(i) on every iteration? By the way does that mean return is like a constant? It can only return one value?

Comment: @cresjoy: There are many options, it all depends on what you want to do.  If you want to return a collection of values, this would be a good opportunity to learn about arrays.  (They're not complicated.)  Either way, we've really moved well outside the scope of the original question being asked.  The question of why the compiler was giving you an error has been answered.  The question of "teach me Java" is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm self teaching, and trying to go in the order of the book I have selected, thats all. Thanks anyways

Comment: I've added my solution which works, looks awful to me for some reason though

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't let you do that because what happens if the `if (num % i == 0)` is never true?

The methods return type is `int`, so it has to return an `int`. And it's possible that the if statement could be false, not every condition is covered with a return statement.

So if you wanted to you could return something like -1, or another invalid value. Then you know that the function didn't find what it was looking for.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to think of a way to sort this issue. Thanks for the help